# ReferenceError: definePageMeta is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vitest

**Description**:

In my vue 3 and nuxt 3 project, i'm using vitest for test. But i've a problem when i run test:

```
ReferenceError: definePageMeta is not defined
 - /pages/client/login.vue:869:5
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:156:18
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7190:25
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7151:36
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5555:7
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5521:9
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5007:11
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5664:11
 - /node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.cjs.js:182:19
 - /node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5770:51
      
undefined
```

**Versions**

- "nuxt": "^3.5.2"
- "vitest": "^0.32.2"
- "jsdom": "^22.1.0"
- "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.0"

Here is my page code:

```js
<template>
  <p>My page</p>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'layout',
  middleware: 'authorized',
})
</script>
```

Here is my test `mytest.spec.ts`:

```js
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import setupTest from 'tests/setupTest'
import Page from 'pages/client/page.vue'

setupTest()

describe('Page', () => {
  it('is a Vue instance', () => {
    expect(Page).toBeTruthy()
    const wrapper = mount(Page)
  })
})
```

Here is my `vitest.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
    AutoImport({
      imports: ['vue'],
      dirs: ['composables', 'components', 'utils', 'stores', 'pages'],
    }),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    coverage: {
      provider: 'istanbul',
      reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html'],
    },
  },
})
```

Thank for your support.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your Nuxt? `npx nuxi dev`

Comment: @ReaganM i tried again but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used the "export default" code variant instead of "definePageMeta":

```js
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  layout: 'no-header',
}
</script>
```

I'm not really sure why this is working, but maybe someone can add a hint.